# Is it possible to find the original filepath of a CSS file with inspect element?

Tags: css, webpack, next.js, path, babeljs

I'm looking at a Next.js Project which uglified and redone filepaths with webpack and babel. Is it possible for me to find the original source of a CSS file?

Comment: Assuming this is a project done by others, then you are out of luck. However, if this is your own project, you can consider enable Source Maps: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/source-maps